# RelayCommand has some invalid arguments

Tags: c#, icommand, relaycommand, invalid-argument

I must not be understanding commands.
I started by looking at this page 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/238657/How-to-use-Commands-in-WPF

and for some reason, RelayCommand is saying that it has some invalid arguments, but I'm not sure why or how to make them correct parameters.

this is the code I have right now

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  private ICommand DeleteCommand
  {
    get;
    internal set;
  }

  public bool CanExecuteDeleteCommand()
  {
    //code here
  }

  public void DeleteExecute()
  {
    //code here 
  }

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    DeleteCommand = new RelayCommand(DeleteExecute, CanExecuteDeleteCommand);
  }
}
```

I removed some code that doesn't have to do with this, I don't think it's effecting any of this, but if you think it might, i can post that stuff too, it's completely unrelated.
if there's any information about this, that'd be awesome.

Comment: Look at your actual code again. MVVMLight's `RelayCommand` is fine initialized that way, assuming `CanExecuteDeleteCommand` and `DeleteExecute` method signature is as posted in this question. I tried here, and my code compiled fine.

Comment: I guess I was a bit confused, I googled RelayCommand and found that microsoft had one so I included that reference (microsoft.something.controls) and included the namespace but that was the wrong RelayCommand, which is very confusing. So i downloaded MVVMLight and installed it to my project with the NuGet manager so it's in my packages folder for my project, but I still don't know what namespace the MVVMLight RelayCommand is in.